# paypal system error/merchant not accepting payments of this type

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am half way done with this project but I am running into some problems. I am trying to accept payment on my android app using paypal integration. When its time for me to make a payment I get two errors. When I try to pay using my paypal login information I get system error please try again later and then when I try to pay using a card information I get payment failed: the merchant does not accept payments of this type. I am not sure what is going on. Can someone please help me. Thanks in advance. Here is my code

```
    public class PaymentPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE=7777;

    private static PayPalConfiguration config=new PayPalConfiguration().environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX)
            .clientId(Config.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID);

    Button btnpaynow;
    EditText edtamount;

    String amount;


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_payment_page);
        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black));

        //start paypal service
        Intent intent=new Intent(this,PayPalService.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
        startService(intent);

        btnpaynow=findViewById(R.id.btnPayNow);
        edtamount=findViewById(R.id.edtAmount);

        btnpaynow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                processPayment();
            }
        });




    }

    private void processPayment() {
        amount=edtamount.getText().toString();
        PayPalPayment payPalPayment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("1.75"), "USD", "ad",PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
        Intent intent=new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION,config);
        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT,payPalPayment);
        startActivityForResult(intent,PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {

        if(requestCode==PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE){
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                PaymentConfirmation confirmation=data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if(confirmation!=null){
                    try {
                        String paymentDetails=confirmation.toJSONObject().toString(4);
                        startActivity(new Intent(this, PayPalPaymentDetails.class).
                                putExtra("Payment Details",paymentDetails)
                        .putExtra("Amount",amount)
                        );

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }else if(resultCode== Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else if(resultCode==PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Invalid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why `.toString(4)`?

Comment: I was following this tutorial and they put that so I put it. Is it not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

> when I try to pay using a card information I get payment failed: the merchant does not accept payments of this type. I am not sure what is going on

What is going on is exactly that. Payments of type 'card' cannot be accepted by that account. You are using a very old deprecated SDK. It will not work.

If you need to accept PayPal payments via a native SDK, the Braintree Mobile SDK is the only supported one: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/accept-payments/express-checkout/ec-braintree-sdk/get-started/ .  A webservice is required for the server-side portion of this integration.

---

Otherwise, integrate a non-native JavaScript PayPal checkout, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/

Comment: thanks for replying. I am using firebase for my web server so I'm not sure  how the braintree mobile sdk will work for that. Can you tell me what I will have to do?

Comment: Read up on how to implement a braintree integration, including the server-side portion, and do it